# Relation between checkers and chess

Tags: learning, tactics, psychology

After watching [GM Vasyl Ivanchuk's victory against GM Baadur Jobava in checkers,](http://youtube.com/watch?v=EnIbviCB4yU) I have a question in my mind:

**Is it possible to relate checkers with the tactical knowledge of chess? If so, how?**

Answer (score 4):

While tactical skills (calculating accurately several moves ahead) can definitely translate, everything else is completely different

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how can it be translated from the tactical skill of chess?

Comment: You have spent hours trying to figure out how the board will look after a sequence of forced moves

Comment: Because of the forced capture rule, it is also easier to calculate deeper into lines than chess. Much less branching to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Checkers is at the point where it is all memorization.  For Fischer chess was too close to that for him to really enjoy it any more.

For most of us chess still has enough problems to solve to keep us interested.

Answer (score 0):

Checkers can in no means be related to Chess. CHECKERS HAS ALREADY BEEN SOLVED - i.e., there is an algorithm that can produce optimal moves from any position, and the algorithm states that the person with the first move wins with best play by both sides. So all a person has got to do is to memorise a few lines and walk up to a checkers tournament and immediately claim first place.

Chess is different in the fact that games still mostly end in wins/losses. There are still many aspects in chess which are unsolvable which keeps chess alive and enjoyable.